# "It's only a matter of time until..."

Tags: syntactic-analysis, extraposition

Is this construction an example of extraposition?

> It's only a matter of time **until all hell breaks loose**

Normally extraposition involves infinitive phrases or that-clauses, but it seems like the clause "until all hell breaks loose" is an extraposed subject. In other words, "Until all hell breaks loose is just a matter of time."

Comment: No, it's not extraposition _it_. It's a temporal Dummy _it_ subject, as in _It's Valentine's day, It's Valentine's Day in only a month, It's only a month to/till Valentine's Day, It's only a matter of time until `X` happens_.

Comment: But "a matter of time" isn't an event nor a time period. It's a subject that concerns time.

Comment: Neither is a month. _A matter of time_ is an idiom for _inevitable_.

Comment: Tangent: is "temporal dummy" really the term for the role played by *it* above? And in general, in clauses such as "it's hard to figure out the name for this role", "it remains to be seen whether we will find the answer"? I'm not seeing the term used that way in a quick search.

Comment: Does the original statement means something like this? "The question is not whether all hell will break loose; the question is only the amount of time before all hell breaks loose."

Comment: @PaulBrinkley  "It's hard to figure out..." and "it remains to be seen..." are both examples of extraposition.  They are syntactic transformations of "to figure out the name ... is hard" and "whether we will find out the answer remains to be seen" respectively.